# How do I create a complex Excel drop down menu?

Tags: excel, vba

How would I go about making a drop down menu in *Excel* as in the picture below?

For example, if the person were to choose something else besides `Paint Grid`, they could choose `Door Grid` below it. Different options to fill it out would then appear based on what was selected.

*Excel* would look in that sheet. For example, if they choose `Door Grid` below they would then have to fill out `Body Gauge` to get a weight that was calculated on the `Door Grid` sheet.

[image]

Comment: What did you made so far? Try to reformulate your question.

Comment: Lookup "data validation dropdown".

Answer (score 3):

You could do it via a combo box in a userform,

This is the code to load the initial values into the `Combobox1`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim x

    For Each x In Range("A2:A5")
       ComboBox1.AddItem x
    Next

End Sub
```

Than once a value is selected, have `ComboBox2`populated,

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

  Dim values

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
          Case "a"
            ComboBox2.Clear
            For Each values In Range("B2:B5")
               ComboBox2.AddItem values
            Next
          Case "b"
            ComboBox2.Clear
            For Each values In Range("C2:C5")
               ComboBox2.AddItem values
            Next
          Case "c"
            ComboBox2.Clear
            For Each values In Range("D2:D5")
               ComboBox2.AddItem values
            Next
     End Select
End Sub
```

The result looks like this,

This is what your sheet looks like that holds the values,

[image]

And this is how it looks when up and running,

[image]

---

Or you could go the other way and do it on the sheet.

[This web site](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/) has a great explanation of how to do it and I could not do a better explanation here so I am linking it.